# Page is not loading in side iframe

Tags: html

I am not able to open link inside iframe. If I open w3schools.com it works fine. but for google, facebook it not able to see it in iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com" height="800px">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Those sites likely have something in their response which checks for an iframe and either denies the content or tries to lead the user to visit the page in the full browser.

Comment: Exactly as @David said. It's called cross-origin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Facebook have been blocked every possiblity to use `iFrame` tag in the website.
If you are trying to add facebook like button or any facebook "Gadgets" you might go into [facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/) where you can generate those codes.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276036/open-facebook-page-in-iframe-or-frame?rq=1)

Comment: What? He's asking about IFrames, not about Forms...

Comment: @l4mpi oh my bad, wait for my edit.

Comment: Your edit won't help. Google does not allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I've edit, and I knownledge with that issue danny.

Comment: @l4mpi I've been edited.

Comment: what exactly cross-origin means? is it"Those sites likely have something in their response which checks for an iframe and either denies the content or tries to lead the user to visit the page in the full browser" mention by david

Comment: @user2826111 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing